# Skip optional TemplateRole in DocuSign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I have a template with two signers. One of them is mandatory but the second one is optional. When I try to create an envelope without a filled second templateRole I receive INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT error. Is it possible to conditionally delete templateRole in the envelope with all 'SignHere' tabs?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to go about this would be through Conditional Routing.

One of the ways you could go about making this work is to set the optional template role to be conditional based on a specific tab value. Say a text or checkbox. If you were to make these fields read-only and populate them on send, the first recipient would not be able to edit the value.

When our system sees the presence of this value, say a checkbox being checked, it can then follow the logic that you provide to drop the template role.

IE: When sending place a read-only checkbox set to be checked if you want the second recipient to take part.

When the first recipient finishes their portion, Conditional Routing engages. When it sees the checkbox is populated, it knows to send to the second role. If it doesn't see the value populated, that role is then ignored.

Does that make sense? An outline and setup guides for Conditional routing can be found on our support page at https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-conditional-recipients -- the portion for setting this up for an envelope or template in the WebUI is about halfway down the page.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Alternative: omitting a role or signer object will delete the recipient and their tabs. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply not include a role object (template reference pattern) or signer object (composite templates) for the role that you're not interested in. Omitting a role/signer object will remove that recipient, and their tabs, from the envelope.

Here's an example using the [API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Server%20template%20with%20two%20signers)

First run the example as is, then try it again but delete a role object.